# Postgres - append to jsonb string

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

In Postgres, I have a `jsonb` column `foo` which stores an array of strings

```
["a","b","c"]
```

I need a query which appends another string to whatever is currently there, at a specified index

```
e.g. Append "!" at index 1

run query: ["a","b","c"] -> ["a","b!","c"]
run again: ["a","b","c"] -> ["a","b!!","c"]
run again: ["a","b","c"] -> ["a","b!!!","c"]
```

I've implemented this in Postgres v11.2 as follows

```sql
UPDATE my_table 
SET foo = jsonb_set(foo, '{1}', CONCAT('"', foo->>1, '!', '"')::jsonb) 
WHERE id = '12345';
```

<sub>*Note the index `1` and the string `'!'` are just hardcoded here for simplicity - but they'd be variables.*</sub>

It works, but I find it quite inelegant. As you can see, I'm selecting out the string at the given index as `text` using the `->>` operator, using that as input to `CONCAT` to append the `'!'`, and also to build that back into the correct syntax to convert back to a `jsonb` string. There is just a lot more work going on here than seems necessary, simply to append to a string at a given path.

**Is there a simpler way to do this?** A built-in function or operator perhaps, or a simpler way of appending than using `CONCAT`? (I tried using the `||` operator in various ways but couldn't seem to make anything work with the syntax & types)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a better way than `jsonb_set()`.

The concat can be replaced by `||` as follows:

```
jsonb_set(foo, '{1}', ('"' || (foo->>1) || '!"')::jsonb)
```

Comment: Thanks - that was the `||` syntax I was looking for! That's already a big improvement.